# Slow Django many to many query

Tags: django, postgresql

I have 9 Million records.
It will be 200M soon.
It can take 15min + to fetch this:

[image]

```
class Follower():

    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(
       "instagram_data.Hashtag", verbose_name=_("hashtags_name"))

class Hashtag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("HashtagName"), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, unique=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Ubunto htop:
[image: ![]

I think it reverse lookup for all values.
I think it will have maybe 2000 records found.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: probably have better luck running raw sql for this type of thing. minimize any joins if you don't need them. can use common table expressions (with clause) to narrow results down before adding additional where clauses.

Comment: Well I did tried some SQL on pgadmin. It wss still slow, not this specific usecase. fetch a BOOLEAN on Followers.is_business == True took 3 minutes from 9M raws, it has db_index=True btw, might be server related ?

Answer (score 1):

The image you post looks like the model admin, if that is the case try adding the field `hashtags` to the [`raw_id_fields` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) of the model admin (although then you won't get the select tag and will have to manually enter the id/pk) or the [`autocomplete_fields` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) which would use `select2` to load the choices asychronously. This would work something like:

```py
class HashtagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name']

class FollowerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['hashtags']


admin.site.register(Follower, FollowerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Hashtag, HashtagAdmin)
```

If this is not in the model admin you can change the widget you use in the form on the form class (you will need to build a custom widget or look for some package that provides widget that can allow comma separted values), or you can use the package [Django-Select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to give the user a searchable select tag (again using select2).

Comment: Well the issue is slowness not functionality. I was not following your suggestions. and yes this is the search at the admin panel, I use djangoql, it works fine.